# Nested heatmap with ggcorrplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, heatmap, correlation, pearson-correlation

I have a data set that has two variables, Treatment and Trait. I'd like to make a correlation heat map showing the relationship between each treatment, nested within the traits. I'm not sure if I am even using the right terminology so here is an example.

This is a regular correlation heat map using `ggcorrplot()` and the `mtcars` data set.

```
library(ggcorrplot)    

data(mtcars)

corr <- round(cor(mtcars), 1)

ggcorrplot(corr,hc.order = TRUE, type = "upper",
           outline.col = "white")
```

[image]

Now I add another column to that data set, named 'var'.

```
    var<-data.frame(var = sample(c("a", "b", "c",'d','e'), 32, replace = TRUE))

    mtcars<-cbind(mtcars, var)

    head(mtcars)

#                   mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb var
#Mazda RX4         21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4   c
#Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4   c
#Datsun 710        22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1   d
#Hornet 4 Drive    21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1   b
#Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2   c
#Valiant           18.1   6  225 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1   b
```

How can I then include the separate correlations of the `var` column in the plot? Almost like a `facet_wrap()` type move...?

Here is an example of what it would look like:

[image]